# Sending/Setting a value to a Password Field on a Website

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, passwords

I have written a small application that needs to log in to a website to perform some actions.
The problem is that whenever I try to set the password field on the website it doesn't accept the password.

I have found a way around this by using the SendKeys function. The problem with that is that it requires focus and the program requires to run in the background.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is an example of how you'd set the Username Field:

```
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("field-username").SetAttribute("value", "UserName")
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: what is webBackground? this is a normal html page?

Comment: It's the WebBrowser component

Comment: Does the site do something with the password field using Javascript consuming its keydown/up/press events? Debug the form fields using Fiddler, see what gets sent.

Comment: Ran Fiddler and I see no keypress/up/down events...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is as follows:

```
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("field-loginFormPassword").SetAttribute("maxLength", "20")
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("field-loginFormPassword").SetAttribute("value", "yourpassword")
```

By changing the "maxlength" value it allows you to set the "value" to the desired text and then you can submit the Form and it will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [mshtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you guys, I found the answer on how to do it. Took me the better part of the day. It's relatively easy if you know what to look for :)

Comment: Thank you to you all for the suggestions :)

Comment: Please post your solution, I have also run into this problem @XantorAmnobius