# Searching for an E-Mail provider with different passwords for Login, SMTP and POP

Tags: email, passwords, smtp, pop3

I'm searching for an `E-Mail` provider (for free) where you can set up different passwords for `POP` and `SMTP` and Login access.

So far `Google-Search` hasn't found anything useful about this.

Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: What is the purpose? Do you want multiple mailboxes to perform some tests? Each account should have its own password.

Comment: @Alexei I want to implement a licensing system that works over mail. This sounds strange at the first moment, I know, but I'm trying to make it the most simple it can be for me as developer. The program uses already a POP-fetch for the main functionality, so it would be logical to use the same sort of functionality for the licence system (it should be really simple because it is not worth to set up a server in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, licensing should be done using a `Licence Manager` that should be hosted on a Web Server that is reachable by your application (that is deployed on your client's machine or run on the Web).

An example of an implementation of a licensing system is shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99499/Implementation-of-the-Licensing-System-for-a-Softw#_Toc266779058) and you should take a look before starting coding.

However, if you insist on using e-mails for validation, you can embed a `Web Browser` control (or a div, iframe or something similar) and ask the user to create a free account on some e-mail provider. All major e-mail providers use CAPTCHAs, that's why human input is required.

It looks like it is possible to [set password fields values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903313/sending-setting-a-value-to-a-password-field-on-a-website), so your application can set the password and use the account from now on.

However, this solution seems really ugly to me and also might confuse the users, since they might enter their e-mail account credentials by mistake.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will try that.